# What are the nonverbal spells used in Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

What are the nonverbal  spells used in *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*?

For example, when the Auror protects himself ? Or the spell he used to enter within the wall and to appear near Nagini?

Comment: I didn't hear any non-verbal spells...

Comment: I have a feeling a lot of these will be unknowns. For example, for the two you cite the screenplay only says: _"In a flash, GRIMMSON conjures a domed Shield Charm around himself and IRMA’S body."_ and doesn't say anything about him entering the wall.

Comment: Well, it's too bad, it would have growth the knowledge we already have in spells, but thank you @TheLethalCarrot !

Comment: I imagine some are shown and some can be worked out mind you but I only glanced at your examples

Answer (score 2):

Spells are marked with a timestamp of when they occur during the film.

(var.) indicates a possible variation of the spell most likely used.

Quotes ‘’ indicate wording taken directly from the screenplay.

[4m]  Grindelwald transfigures the chariot reins into snakes. (var. of Serpensortia)

[5m]  Grindelwald ‘touches the Elder Wand to the river’ and fills the chariot with water. (both Evanesco and Auguamenti)

[6m]  Spielman’s wand ‘melts into dust.’ (var. of Evanesco)

[7m]  Spielman stops his fall just before hitting water (Arresto Momentum)

[25m]  Newt siphons water off his clothing (Tergeo)

[45m]  Newt uses his wand to hear sounds from the past (var. of his Appare Vestigium spell)

[53m]  Auror Grimmson camouflages himself in the wall (var. of the Disillusionment Charm)

[54m]  Grimmson ‘conjures a domed Shield Charm around himself and Irma’s body.’ (Protego)

[1h 7m]  McGonagall first reverses, then reapplies Leta’s ‘Oscausi’ charm on a student. (unknown counter-charm)

[1h 26m]  Newt is detected inside the French Ministry, setting off an alarm (Caterwauling charm)

[1h 27m]  Theseus ‘sends a curse’ after Tina and Newt. Tina blocks the curse, sends Theseus flying, and conjures a chair for him. (all unknown) Theseus is bound in the chair. (Incarcerous)

[1h 50m]  An auror uses the killing curse on one of Grindelwald’s fanatics. (Avada Kedavra)

[1h 52m]  Blue flames are created by Grindelwald, which kill the disloyal. (Protego Diabolica) Everyone uses Protego to counter it. The flames later expand and destroy the mausoleum. (var. of Fiendfyre)

[1h 56m]  Leta ‘points her wand at the skull in Rosier’s hands, which explodes.’ (Confringo)

[2h 3m]  Dumbledore is freed from his metal cuffs. (Evanesco or Emancipare)